# Web animation API event

Tags: javascript, web-animations, web-animations-api

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>    
    <div id="div1"></div>
</body>
<script>
const Divtarget = document.getElementById("div1");
class animasi{
  constructor(){
   this.effect1 = [{width: "200px", 
      backgroundColor:"blue"},{width: "1000px"} ];
   this.opsi1 = {duration: 5000, fill:  "forwards",
     delay: 5000};
    }
}
const getanime = new animasi();
const keyframEffect1 = new KeyframeEffect(Divtarget,getanime.effect1,getanime.opsi1);
const animation1 = new Animation(keyframEffect1,document.timeline);

animation1.play();

Divtarget.addEventListener("animationend",function change(){
    const body = document.getElementById("body");
    body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});

Divtarget.removeEventListener("animationend",function change(){
    const body = document.getElementById("body");
    body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
</script>
</html>
```

I want to use `animationend` event on web animation API, but when the animation is ended the call back function is not called. Why did this happen? Do animation events like `animationstart`, `animationend`, `animationiteration`, `animationcancel` work with an animation event?

Comment: not your issue, but your lucky that `Divtarget.removeEventListener` won't actually remove the completely different callback you added with `Divtarget.addEventListener`

Comment: Also, why have you double spaced your code? it's actually annoying to read like that

Comment: How the solution look like sir

Comment: You should read some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation) - the Animation instance has some methods/properties that may assist you

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'finish' listener to the `animation1`

```js
const Divtarget = document.getElementById("div1");
class animasi {
  constructor() {
    this.effect1 = [{
        width: "200px",
        backgroundColor: "blue"
      },
      {
        width: "1000px"
      }
    ];
    this.opsi1 = {
      duration: 1000,
      fill: "forwards",
      delay: 100
    };
  }
}
const getanime = new animasi();
const keyframEffect1 = new KeyframeEffect(Divtarget, getanime.effect1, getanime.opsi1);
const animation1 = new Animation(keyframEffect1, document.timeline);

// NOTE this
animation1.addEventListener('finish',  function change() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});


animation1.play();
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```